# Unable to backup Firestore to google cloud storage using github actions: wrong project id

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, github-actions

I want to backup Firestore to google could storage, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNT_9d0gAFQ) and [this](https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-automated-backups/) (they're the same, one video, the other is an article). The Github repo is private, it belongs to a GitHub organization that I'm the owner of. I created a GitHub cron action

```
name: Backup Firestore

on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 0 * * *'

env:
  PROJECT_ID: project-id
  BUCKET: gs://storage-bucket-url
  
jobs:
  backup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: GoogleCloudPlatform/github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
      with:
        service_account_key: ${{ secrets.FIRESTORE }}
        export_default_credentials: true
    - run: gcloud info
    - run: gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID
    - run: gcloud firestore export $BUCKET
```

Github gives me this error

> ERROR: (gcloud.firestore.export) NOT_FOUND: Project 'project-id' does
> not exist.

I have double-checked the project id, it is correct, the bucket URL is correct, user privileges are correct, the secret is correct as well, I have watched the video 3 times and read the tutorial and can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: Can you try explicitly referencing the Project `gcloud firestore export ... --project=${PROJECT_ID}`?

Comment: I'm assuming the error doesn't actually reference `project-id` and that you changed it to obfuscate your actual project

Comment: @DazWilkin I just tried to explicitly reference the project, no luck

Comment: I tried it using the link you provided and it works for me as-is. Can you confirm that you're replacing the value of `PROJECT_ID` in the script with your project ID. Your question uses `project-id` and I'm unsure whether this is the value that you're using or an actual project ID. In my case, the project ID is `dazwilkin-201003-64183734` and that's the value I'm using the `backup.yaml`

Comment: I'm using the project id as in `dazwilkin-201003-64183734` or `example123`, the one you see in google could console when you click on the top left side.

Comment: Do you have `gcloud` installed? If so, can you run `gcloud firestore export gs://${BUCKET} --project=${PROJECT_ID}` from a shell? Either replace the values or set the environment variables beforehand. This will run as your user account but should succeed.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs) job to send an authenticated POST request to the Firebase API. This would keep the code for your DB backups and the DB itself in the same place.